# Can you turn off object visibility in a separate window?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, empty

Just for the sake of modeling something, I wanted to have two Blender windows, each on separate monitors and have one show the model and empty references images and the other to only show the model. Is this possible?

Right now I have the two windows, and both showing the model and reference photo empties, but of course if I use the outliner to control viewport visibility of an object, it does so for both windows. I seem to remember that there was a way to make viewports independent, but maybe that was an older version of Blender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to take advantage of local view.

- Set up your second 3DViewport exactly like your first and move it to your second monitor.
- In that viewport select only the items you want to have visible.
- Type <kbd>/</kbd> to enter [*Local View*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/local_view.html)

Everything except the selected objects will seem to disappear.

The <kbd>/</kbd> key is a toggle, so you can switch between local and global view.  But if you switch back to global view remember that the next time you switch to Local view only the things you have selected at that moment will appear.

Comment: That's a useful method too. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Because it is an empty that you want to hide, one convenient way of hiding only those in a single viewport is to deselect empty from the new Object Types Visibility menu at the top right of the 3D viewport as show in the screenshot below.

[image: Object Types Visibility]

In the screenshot below it shows a split viewport where the top one has two image reference empties that are visible and in the bottom one it has the same cube object visible, but without the image reference empties.

[image: Split Viewport with empties turned off]